# How to speed up postgresql point in time restore

Tags: postgresql, pgbackrest, point-in-time-recovery

I am using pgbackrest for a postgresql database backup and restore, do you know which database or pgbackrest parameters can be used to adjust the performance of postgresql database point in time restore?
Thank you.

Comment: Not really. Which part of the restore is too slow?

Comment: There were thousands of wal files to be replayed in point in time recovery, this replay took a lot of time. Not sure if there is a way to speed up the replay process.

Comment: There is no way to speed up replay. Perhaps you should take base backups more often.